# The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, nvarchar

I have a query like below:

```
select 
  ...
 convert(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(day,t.DAYNUMBER,t.START_DATE), 103) AS END_DATE
 where END_DATE >=  GETDATE()
```

It displays the following error:

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value.

t.DAYNUMBER comes from:

```
select max([day]) from TOUR_SPECIFIKA
```

where day is int. And t.START_DATE is date. I don't know why it shows nvarchar in error.

Comment: What **value** are you trying to convert here??

Comment: t.start_date is date

Comment: Based on the syntax, you seem to be using SQL Server.  You should also tag the question with the version.

Comment: @marc_s T.START_DATE is date type and daynumber is int. what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you have this code:

```
select ...,
       convert(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(day, t.DAYNUMBER, t.START_DATE), 103) AS END_DATE
where END_DATE >= GETDATE()
```

And you are getting that particular error, then either `t.START_DATE` or `t.END_DATE` are `nvarchar()` rather than some date/time data type.  One of these columns contains an invalid date.

Note that the reference in the `where` clause is to a column in one of the tables.  It is *not* a reference to the alias in the `SELECT`.

Comment: @LauretaXhaferraj . . . If you want an answer to the question, edit your question and explain which value is `nvarchar()`.  Tag the question with the appropriate version of SQL Server (as I already asked in a comment).  Sample data would also be useful.